# Tailwind + Nextjs setting line-height globally using _document <body className"leading-snug">

Tags: next.js, tailwind-css

I have a nextjs and am using tailwindcss. I would like to set some default styles for the entire project. Originally I did this by wrapping my `_app.tsx` with a div and styled this div using tailwind. Now I am using the `_document.tsx` and am styling the  tag.

```
  render() {
    return (
      <Html>
        <Head>
          <link
            href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=DM+Sans:ital,wght@0,400;0,500;0,700;1,500;1,700&display=swap"
            rel="stylesheet"
          />
        </Head>
        <body className="bg-slate-900 text-lg leading-3 text-white">
          <Main />
          <NextScript />
        </body>
      </Html>
    )
  }
```

I was able to succesfully change background colour and font colour with this method. However when I try to set the line-height like this it does not work.
My questions are:

- Is this a common way to style a nextjs app with tailwind or is there some commonly accepted way to do this that I don't know about?
- Why is can I not set the line height with this method?

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in the [Tailwind CSS document - Overriding default line-heights](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/line-height#overriding-default-line-heights), the `Font Size` classes have implemented different `line height` by default. You cannot override it without setting a breakpoint-specific line-height. You can also [customize](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/font-size#customizing-your-theme) your font-size classes without adding any initial line-height property so that you can add different line-height classes.

Example:

```
<div className="text-lg leading-loose md:text-xl md:leading-loose">
  <Main />
  <NextScript />
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

To address your questions

> Is this a common way to style a nextjs app with tailwind or is there some commonly accepted way to do this that I don't know about?

Yes, Tailwind itself provide information about integrating Tailwind with Nextjs [here](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/guides/nextjs).

> Why is can I not set the line height with this method?

`line-height` is an inheritable property meaning that if you set it somewhere, all the child elements will inherit that value (pretty much like some other properties like `font`, `color` ... etc.)

Now to answer your question about why it isn't applied, there are two possible scenarios.

1. There is something else overriding its value (like if there is a different UI library you're using).
2. It's applied but it works in a different way than you expect. The value you are using in the example uses the `rem` as the unit. This will translate to a fixed value. In your case, `leading-3` is equal to `12px` which will definitely look very poor on your page. You should change that to the relative units (`leading-none`, `leading-tight`, `leading-snug`, `leading-normal`, `leading-relaxed`, and `leading-loose`) to make that `line-height` relevant to the `font-size` value of your text. Then it will work as you expect.

To find the cause, you can use the Styles panel in Google Chrome's dev-tools (or any other similar tools in other browsers).

[image: Screenshot from the styles panel in Google Chrome]

Make sure you activate on "Show all" to see the inherited properties. Upon expanding the property, you will see the cascade (all the values trying to be applied to the element) and the value that belongs to the selector with the highest specificity will win.